# SCD Type - 2 implementation in IICS (Informatica Cloud)

Tags: cloud, etl, informatica, informatica-cloud

I am new in IICS. Does anyone please help me implement SCD type 2?  Or any walk-through tutorial weblink.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented using code and invoke through Informatica

create two table

```
select * from db.Customer_Source
select * from EDW.Customer_Master





INSERT INTO dbo.Customer_Master           --Insert into master 
SELECT
    Source_Cust_ID,
    First_Name,
    Last_Name,
    Eff_Date,
    End_Date,
    Current_Flag
FROM
    ( MERGE EDW.Customer_Master CM
        USING EDW.Customer_Source CS                                             
    ON (CM.Source_Cust_ID = CS.Source_Cust_ID)                                
    
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT VALUES (CS.Source_Cust_ID, CS.First_Name, CS.Last_Name,
        convert(char(10), getdate()-1, 101), '12/31/2199', 'y')                         -- if not match then insert new values
        
    WHEN MATCHED AND CM.Current_Flag = 'y' AND (CM.Last_Name <> CS.Last_Name ) THEN            -- if match then it will insert new row and fkag records as "Y" and old one as "N" 
         UPDATE SET CM.Current_Flag = 'n', CM.End_date = convert(char(10), getdate()-2, 101)
    OUTPUT $Action Action_Out,
            CS.Source_Cust_ID,
            CS.First_Name,
            CS.Last_Name,
            convert(char(10), getdate()-1, 101) Eff_Date,
            '12/31/2199' End_Date,
            'y'Current_Flag)
AS MERGE_OUT
WHERE MERGE_OUT.Action_Out = 'UPDATE';
```

Answer (score 0):

In IICS there is pre built mapping for SCD-2. It is totally parameterized. you can check that. You just need to change source and target parameters there. Really easy. Give it a try.